# Почему не стоит запятая перед «или»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, или, пояснение

Из учебника:

*Переход вещества из жидкого состояния в твёрдое называют отвердеванием или кристаллизацией*.

Пояснение в глаза бросается, но почему-то оно не обособлено.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В учебнике написано правильно. Запятая не ставится.

[**Пояснительные конструкции**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119), пункт 2:

> **Примечания:** 1. Следует различать пояснительный союз *или* (в значении ‘то есть’, перед ним ставится запятая) и разделительный союз *или* (перед ним запятая не ставится, если союз не повторяется). Ср.: *Флексия, **или окончание**, имеется только у слов, относящихся к изменяемым частям речи* — повторить союз нельзя, его можно заменить союзом *то есть*; *Изменяемая часть слова в конце его называется **флексией или окончанием*** — здесь разделительный союз может быть повторен (*…называется или флексией, или окончанием*).